# Android: How to enable users to rearrange elements in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

iOS has the ability to allow the user to rearrange/reorder elements in a list.

This is done by going into Edit mode and dragging the elements to the required location.

A good example of this is the Edit mode in the Notifications screen in the Settings app.

[image: iOS notification edit example]

Does there exist this kind of functionality in Android by default? Is it possible to enable this functionality within ListView or LinearLayout?

If this doesn't exist in the base Android functionality is there a library that does a similar thing?

I know of the drag and drop functionality, but this is most likely too low level as far as I can tell.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: yes, you can do it in any os

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some third party libraries available in android

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist

https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview

Comment: cwac-touchlist looks especially good. It's a shame that Android doesn't include functionality like this by default.

Comment: Just a FYI, the Music App in AOSP also has control for this.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example from Google's DevBytes available now.

- Video is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q
- Sourcecode is here: http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ListViewDraggingAnimation.zip

Comment: Great! Semi-official solutions is much better. Still default functionality deserves rays of anger. May it be at least in support lib.

Comment: You are right, this should be part of the API. If you're looking for a way to delete listview entries by swiping them out, here's a semi official solution for that too: https://code.google.com/p/dashclock/source/browse/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/dashclock/ui/SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.java